# In Java 17 getting NullPointer while calling SOAP Webservice

Tags: spring, soap, migration, soap-client, java-17

I am upgrading Java 8 project into Java 17. And in existing code, while calling SOAP webservice in my project and I am getting below error.

Java and Spring Version I am using

```
Java 17
Spring 5.3.22
Spring Boot 2.6.6
```

I am using below dependencies in my gradle:

```
    implementation 'org.glassfish.metro:webservices-api:2.4.4'
    implementation 'org.glassfish.metro:webservices-rt:2.4.4'

**Error:** 
com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.sun.xml.ws.api.EndpointAddress.getURI()" because the return value of "com.sun.xml.ws.api.client.WSPortInfo.getEndpointAddress()" is null
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2055) ~[encrypter-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3966) ~[encrypter-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3989) ~[encrypter-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4950) ~[encrypter-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22] (edited)
```

I tries by adding jakarta namespace dependencies and by changing imports accodingly from javax to jakarta but getting same error with it.

Dependency I used:
implementation 'jakarta.xml.ws:jakarta.xml.ws-api:4.0.0'

I will appreciate your solutions in this! :)